# Powered minecarts pushing paused carts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been attempting to get powered minecarts to push an empty minecart from a break in the track.

```
====R==W========

(R is for raised level & W is for wooden pressure plate)
```

In the track above the powered minecart comes from the left and pushes the empty minecart that is resting on W onto the track and it continues to the right. However the powered minecart *always* gets stuck on the Wooden pressure plate and doesn't continue.

How can I set this up so that the powered cart keeps pushing? I've tried using downward sloping tracks both in front of the W and after but it just keeps getting stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every attempt I've made at using powered carts, they've always come up short in terms of ability to push loads, not stick on things or travel far distances.

It's possible that changing the pushing device from a powered cart to nearby booster track would solve the sticking problem. There are [many, many booster configurations](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecart_booster) that might fit the particular problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking about heading the booster route but they took up a lot of room compared to my final design thoughts. (I wanted it to be fairly compact and adding a booster next to all the carts takes up a lot of room) I've seen a powered cart do it in a video so I guess I'll have to watch it more carefully. I didn't see them do anything special which is what got me more annoyed :)

Comment: I'm going to give the booster a try with a single track that will be able to push any of the paused carts when necessary...I'll post back later when I have the chance to mess with it

Answer (score 2):

Powered carts simply don't push at all when they are not on track, and they don't have the 'excess momentum' that boosters create, so a powered cart will never be able to cross a pressure plate or other track gap by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The cart simple needs to be going fast enough to continue over the gap. Although as Nick said minecart booster speed is about the right speed to go over.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this applied back when this was posted, but in any version that still makes sense to play nowadays, you can replace the pressure plate with a Detector Rail. It will react to minecarts with the same signal strength as a pressure plate, ignore noise caused by mobs walking over the track (or skeleton arrows hitting it), and not stop or even slow down minecarts in any way.